# Outgoing email marked as spam. Can you tell what is wrong from email header?

Tags: spam, spf, dkim

I have a send-only server using postfix. The outgoing email goes to Yahoo's spam folder. It is a test email, the content is very short. I attach the header below. The SPF, DKIM all looks good. Can you tell what is wrong please? Any information would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
X-Apparently-To: someone@yahoo.com; Mon, 20 Mar 2017 03:31:18 +0000
Return-Path: <bounced@someone.com>
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 108.175.3.185
Received-SPF: pass (domain of someone.com designates 108.175.3.185 as permitted sender)
X-YMailISG: e6rIYJ8WLDuk49UoGn3hxSIS2b.KDniejfeBb4NKiIKa1h4a
 tddwWZWiea7y3WiIUc04StH3tVGTgFUaba98qOjriKyhl8WNWZRUVvPohgAX
 4i32_AUxq42LMJc9PuKD3mgcD6rwwpH_SZ9lxS3LcmmsoGatFAboJ4CKvMou
 hNA6FF29ThW9eKVlNSkPwGQ6cSchsk7YAK48Ng67F.Wp3zcrKETCMJrkzOxa
 S2LFGVXeyR4TZpP4227K.Jz4KSn3W1srwqRsl2qW29aMf.VirJvLXuoCOPxi
 ZQJtI_rX0ZT9K1A0L74hb4qe7fNtuiV7aXWP_FmaiBFOVklNFgjjuuFfAfAO
 e2qYM7RK52n.RzShsDLlpCT8fvHTYZ4qtD1FT7XmRqorq48Ft0vEcNw7I33d
 bJd8nBMjstPdTMYEibvf7ifvymFGAWQe20wlBQ_Ecgd49f8L7.7OYOWylJZn
 Z8q.uaLXkFWlElw3GU_SZVjYDYqfykDnisqC72Jycb6LjXtIlLHC97eSMgds
 P8zqhjxxCq1k2.VNT4pG1se1Gt9Ua2skR2CeoyFX1H_mShl5l6fSJHi6MCeL
 Df2MbURrDNmbG8wgARLYKDRJNd_lVLORz7kpsldSjQ2XiPOcpXdI8pXYrXWM
 KK7feYTn3s0znIzQIWN1JMm3DtT43DUOfTitnegl4vszss8p7.vSiNOBy6v.
 1TX.WV2erqeTRIVGisYUPle3l8FDljbuS.6LsPA9S9syC1iDSwJbORp8BufJ
 CM4DxEx5wvSKEPsai26af7cwPH8qJnExNcAYrdxTSDUN.TEnG6rmwVrlX9t5
 kGuYk0sRKL8Ail1QfR.bC24Qx0FvejXy9U9Pd1UOxACVln7jEO4fF_Kofqp5
 rLngsx1Fj9VhkAgxNe36mS8AHa5LNMnxVcSMTRybCxKB3URFdwuhOAdlvKV_
 tBgwWNJYnJwJOa.WmgAYsGkCUuS_qrVkwz1uMfYR7HnF83wjSrAh1Nd4eG_j
 voeiJfhhz.k.EbCFFwDOuVwk__N1nR6NuaMu7ZV..Akm0InYh2mJTgzXdG5M
 39gdYWueaoVJvNEdZ7Qt6mR5rIqmZgYgN4aPnq4HZuh6d8KogFnq7KMilWyj
 e_Qy_BeDbb7AUOkmTsn4BZUcg04dQJdwwBl9XEwYyD7PXGHHYY_Xg8DX_jOw
 sZX9yuFQolv5PhQ4X44kmy5fdDo5X6SojmkJ.7EbW4LJMvx16ODufimnFUNH
 x4FFLxhxtizWdyQDxIr3Rh_TWpV0cUpl9cHPV6efIkhdhto6XwR4LpA5Pl61
 hDFfqjb9BsF_H5D4LMx9NM_NgEq3CBanVvZl1NfFPEflA4ekWbA8M5owdq_o
 mXtMZavXpiWNwaaGfDE.ICp8nIhDY8nnfssB8u4TCKrGqSPm2GhNkA--
X-Originating-IP: [108.175.3.185]
Authentication-Results: mta1195.mail.ne1.yahoo.com  from=someone.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=someone.com; dkim=pass (ok)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO someone.com) (108.175.3.185)
  by mta1195.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Mon, 20 Mar 2017 03:31:18 +0000
Received: from someone.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by someone.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 47C11A0B2B
    for <someone@yahoo.com>; Mon, 20 Mar 2017 03:31:16 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=someone.com; s=mail;
    t=1489980676; bh=Ba3gj8+xBPQLJTahTfzW6RbWQ/XPgESxkCi2B66PSQg=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:From;
    b=ZHIFwlXUiv0qxaHjJL3NDUqNEh1ABvbJ+e/6UJXLurQ1oaqq9d+NNSMRBXUVOIBV/
     op3MnSIcpGoDTsc04SUe2nABgIViMjJVbaq1ahrBBFEqpSPYlFx8YDRoRJ6DWPR07d
     FuWXoq6zxrLJchopEqm/nMayn7Xzsno4mufGDsvI=
Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2017 03:31:16 +0000 (UTC)
From: MailCenter@someone.com
To: someone@yahoo.com
Message-ID: <1017766072.43.1489980676287@someone1.someone.com>
Subject: Test from Someone
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Length: 6

Hello
```

Comment: I don't know what's going on with this message, but your SPF record is broken. You should have spaces in it, not newlines.

Comment: Does its a newly registred domain ? major email provider dont like newer domain

Comment: @Michael: Thank you. I fixed it. Then waited one hour to let the change be seen and tested again. No difference.

Comment: @yagmoth555: yes. The ip address is new. So it is difficult for new comers?

Comment: Yes, they dont disclose their spam policy, but for new domain with new ip they tend to be more shy at first.

Comment: gmail is really good about telling you why the classify an email in whatever fashion they do - try sending a test message to a gmail account...

Answer (score 2):

```
X-Apparently-To: someone@yahoo.com; Mon, 20 Mar 2017 03:31:18 +0000
Return-Path: <bounced@someone.com>
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 108.175.3.185
Received-SPF: pass (domain of someone.com designates 108.175.3.185 as permitted sender)
```

DNS (IP) is blacklisted: **X-YahooFilteredBulk: 108.175.3.185**

> Check DNSBL here: https://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php